# Can more than .DLL of the same name be registered on a machine?

Tags: dll

Can more than .DLL of the same name be registered on a machine?

Eg. If I have MyDLL.dll in both c:\ and c:\MyDLLs, is it possible to register both MyDLL.dll files?  If I do this, which MyDLL.dll will be used if an application tries to access MyDLL.dll?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your question around DLL which implements a COM component.  It actually uses a GUID (globally unique identifier) which it looks up in the registry under hkey_classes_root/clsid and there in the sub-keys is a scheme for pointing to the physical location.

To start understanding this, open the regedit, and do a control-f find the full path to both of the DLLs in question - you'll see exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

(Source: http://www.codenewsgroups.net/vb/t2754-dll-hell-query.aspx)

If they have the same file name then they cannot co-exist in the same
directory. One will have to be renamed, or moved. If they're ActiveX DLLs
then the file name is less important than the associated ProgID/ClsID used
for registration -- except that renaming it might upset a subsequent
uninstall or re-install of the software from that vendor.

Assuming they have different ProgIDs and ClsIDs then there should be no
problem in registering them. *But if you can try to avoid this*.

*P.S. Check the link above for some good insight.*